# leaner algorithm to group a slice of structs by multiple criterion

Tags: algorithm, go

In below code i have implemented a simple strategy relying on `map` to group the data by `DepartmentID`
and `Country`. I then sub-group the data by `Team`.

A runnable example, including benchmark facilities, is at https://play.golang.org/p/oDx39XtEsQs

The relevant pieces of code

```golang
package main

type Country struct {
    Code      string     `json:"code"`
    Employees []Employee `json:"employees"`
}
type Department struct {
    ID        int        `json:"department"`
    Employees []Employee `json:"employees"`
}

type DepartmentCountry struct {
    keyDepartmentCountry
    Employees []Employee `json:"employees"`
}
type DepartmentCountryTeam struct {
    keyDepartmentCountryTeam
    Employees []Employee `json:"employees"`
}
type keyDepartmentCountry struct {
    ID   int    `json:"department"`
    Code string `json:"code"`
}
type keyDepartmentCountryTeam struct {
    ID   int    `json:"department"`
    Code string `json:"code"`
    Team string `json:"team"`
}

type Employee struct {
    ID           int    `json:"id"`
    Name         string `json:"name"`
    DepartmentID int    `json:"departmentid"`
    Country      string `json:"country"`
    Team         string `json:"team"`
}

func main(){
// ...
    // group by department and country values.
    byDeptAndCty := make(map[keyDepartmentCountry]DepartmentCountry)
    for _, employee := range employees {
        key := keyDepartmentCountry{ID: employee.DepartmentID, Code: employee.Country}
        byDeptAndCty[key] = DepartmentCountry{
            keyDepartmentCountry: key,
            Employees:            append(byDeptAndCty[key].Employees, employee),
        }
    }

    // foreach groups,
    for _, dept := range byDeptAndCty {
        fmt.Printf("g1 %#v\n", dept)
        // group employees by team.
        byDeptAndCtyAndTeam := make(map[keyDepartmentCountryTeam]DepartmentCountryTeam)
        for _, employee := range dept.Employees {
            key := keyDepartmentCountryTeam{ID: employee.DepartmentID, Code: employee.Country, Team: employee.Team}
            byDeptAndCtyAndTeam[key] = DepartmentCountryTeam{
                keyDepartmentCountryTeam: key,
                Employees:                append(byDeptAndCtyAndTeam[key].Employees, employee),
            }
        }
        // print team members
        for _, team := range byDeptAndCtyAndTeam {
            fmt.Printf("  sub %#v\n", team)
        }
    }
// ...
}
```

I am searching to implement an algorithm that does not need to allocate so much,
and which possibly performs faster, because my dataset is too big to keep both the `map`
and the original data in memory on the hardware we plan to use.

Comment: One simple optimization would be to build a tree instead of maps of composite keys. That is, map of countries, with each element containing a map of depts, etc.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I did not get it. can you further elaborate so i can try that too ? I have also noticed that using `map`, the allocations greatly varies depending on the shape of the data. Can this be prevented to using a tree ? Which kind of tree ? A trie tree ?

Comment: If you want to save some memory you can use pointers to Employee `Employees []*Employee` in structures used by maps.

Comment: @Jaroslaw indeed, it also helped to reduce allocations a little bit.

Comment: I think that it should be also possible to achieve *streaming* like approach if you need only to print grouped results. Since each Employee contains country, department, and team, you can sort a list of employees by these fields, and when iterating over sorted employees list detect when one of the grouping fields change and print new group starting message.

Comment: @Jaroslaw well i need to iterate over them to count, sum and average, for examples. And then i need to comply we some specific JSON output. But for that last part i can use something like easyJSON, i believe, to make it very lean without much more complicated logic.

Comment: @Jaroslaw, that has O(nlogn) complexity, whereas the map approach has amortized linear complexity.

Comment: @BurakSerdar indeed the net speed performs very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this can be used:

```
countries:=map[string]*CountryData{}

type CountryData struct {
   Country *Country
   Depts map[int]*DeptData
}

type DeptData struct {
   Dept *Department
   Employees []*Employee  // Employees in country-dept
   Teams map[int][]*Employee // Employees in country-dept-team
}
```

The above data structure keeps pointers to the employee/country/department structures, so only one instance of them are in memory. The tree structure with nested maps allow you to traverse the tree using different keys.

Comment: you mean like this https://play.golang.org/p/ov2hliF2zUe ?

Comment: @mh-cbon I can't see any pointers in your link. I don't think he means like this.

Comment: That gives the basic idea, yes. The tree is built using references, so there is no data duplication.

Comment: @TheFool, the relevant code is at the bottom.

Comment: it helps reduce the memory by a factor 10 (like mapPtr, but that one behave slightly less efficiently), which should be good enough, its net speed also performs very well and it is easy to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

previously i had found that sort based solution.

https://play.golang.org/p/RfRmAuJgsj8

```golang
func withSort(employees []Employee, quiet bool) {
    sort.Slice(employees, multiless(
        func(i, j int) bool { return employees[i].DepartmentID < employees[j].DepartmentID },
        func(i, j int) bool { return employees[i].Country < employees[j].Country },
        func(i, j int) bool { return employees[i].Team < employees[j].Team },
    ))
    g1 := and(
        func(i, j int) bool { return employees[i].DepartmentID == employees[j].DepartmentID },
        func(i, j int) bool { return employees[i].Country == employees[j].Country },
    )
    g2 := and(g1,
        func(i, j int) bool { return employees[i].Team == employees[j].Team },
    )
    iter2 := iter2(len(employees), g1)
    for iter2.More() {
        i, j := iter2.Next()
        if !quiet {
            fmt.Printf("g1 %#v\n", employees[i:j])
        }
        sub := iter2.Sub(g2)
        for sub.More() {
            i, j = sub.Next()
            if !quiet {
                fmt.Printf("  sub %#v\n", employees[i:j])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

memory allocations is really reduced, but, the net speed is not as good as the accepted solution.

```
$ go test -v -bench=. -count=1 | prettybench
benchmark                                            iter        time/iter    bytes alloc          allocs
---------                                            ----        ---------    -----------          ------
BenchmarkAll/_____map-__getEmployees-________10-4   44650      26.15 μs/op      2729 B/op    23 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/_____map-__getEmployees-_______100-4   10000     102.03 μs/op     44968 B/op   111 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/_____map-__getEmployees-______1000-4    1834     621.99 μs/op    360355 B/op   177 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/_____map-__getEmployees-_____10000-4     194    6187.37 μs/op   2883473 B/op   243 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/_____map-_getEmployees2-________10-4   46804      25.66 μs/op      2688 B/op    17 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/_____map-_getEmployees2-_______100-4   13699      87.88 μs/op     44672 B/op    40 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/_____map-_getEmployees2-______1000-4    2038     586.26 μs/op    392832 B/op    59 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/_____map-_getEmployees2-_____10000-4     126    8893.38 μs/op   5832321 B/op    96 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/__mapPtr-__getEmployees-________10-4   47112      25.35 μs/op      1561 B/op    24 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/__mapPtr-__getEmployees-_______100-4   14434      83.64 μs/op      6842 B/op   112 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/__mapPtr-__getEmployees-______1000-4    2450     477.21 μs/op     46267 B/op   178 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/__mapPtr-__getEmployees-_____10000-4     276    4400.12 μs/op    361643 B/op   244 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/__mapPtr-_getEmployees2-________10-4   50901      23.82 μs/op       416 B/op    15 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/__mapPtr-_getEmployees2-_______100-4   18030      66.31 μs/op      6176 B/op    31 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/__mapPtr-_getEmployees2-______1000-4    2732     420.04 μs/op     49184 B/op    43 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/__mapPtr-_getEmployees2-_____10000-4     284    4234.28 μs/op    660512 B/op    69 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/____tree-__getEmployees-________10-4   35811      33.35 μs/op      8765 B/op   112 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/____tree-__getEmployees-_______100-4   16935      70.20 μs/op     14045 B/op   200 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/____tree-__getEmployees-______1000-4    4036     286.15 μs/op     53469 B/op   266 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/____tree-__getEmployees-_____10000-4     498    2434.40 μs/op    368865 B/op   332 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/____tree-_getEmployees2-________10-4   51200      23.19 μs/op      1616 B/op    30 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/____tree-_getEmployees2-_______100-4   24274      49.31 μs/op      6864 B/op    53 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/____tree-_getEmployees2-______1000-4    4863     246.96 μs/op     50384 B/op    72 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/____tree-_getEmployees2-_____10000-4     510    2393.52 μs/op    647888 B/op   106 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/____sort-__getEmployees-________10-4   49437      22.20 μs/op       496 B/op    15 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/____sort-__getEmployees-_______100-4   17683      67.53 μs/op       496 B/op    15 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/____sort-__getEmployees-______1000-4    2367     484.35 μs/op       496 B/op    15 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/____sort-__getEmployees-_____10000-4     244    4939.36 μs/op       496 B/op    15 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/____sort-_getEmployees2-________10-4   54217      22.17 μs/op       496 B/op    15 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/____sort-_getEmployees2-_______100-4   20193      59.68 μs/op       496 B/op    15 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/____sort-_getEmployees2-______1000-4    3055     386.61 μs/op       496 B/op    15 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/____sort-_getEmployees2-_____10000-4     310    3758.04 μs/op       496 B/op    15 allocs/op
ok      test/d/sort/post    48.982s
```

At the cost of some memory the accepted solution offers an easier maintenance with much better net speed.

```
BenchmarkAll/_____map-__getEmployees-_____10000-4     194    6187.37 μs/op   2883473 B/op   243 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/____sort-__getEmployees-_____10000-4     244    4939.36 μs/op       496 B/op    15 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/__mapPtr-__getEmployees-_____10000-4     276    4400.12 μs/op    361643 B/op   244 allocs/op
BenchmarkAll/____tree-__getEmployees-_____10000-4     498    2434.40 μs/op    368865 B/op   332 allocs/op
```

Comment: Could you paste full code used in your benchmark?

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark. It is worth knowing that the performance difference between the two implementations appears so early.

Comment: @Jaroslaw yeeeessss; we can put it like this. When i think to it twice it appears so obvious i feel stupid of trying to be too clever by half but not nearly smart enough to figure that out directly. Thats life. Eating my hat.